# Why would a host block ICMP echo (ping response) yet it allows me to connect to it?

Tags: icmp

Is there a security reason for that?

[image]

Comment: Yes - An OK ping response confirms there is something there. So worth a port scan to find something possibly interesting. No response, move on another target. That said a lot of the time people will just scan  every ip for every port. In that case it makes no difference one way or another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well the main reason to block ICMP is to avoid ping flood attacks

**Ping flood attack**

It is performed by sending ICMP request to the host in uncontrolled way so that tcp/ip stack of recievers gets busy and will occupies servers valuable resources

More over if server is protected From ICMP related attacks. ICMP with large payload can be exploited to eat up network bandwidth

Comment: There is no IP packet which is simpler to respond to than an ICMP echo request. Thus any reasonable implementation can respond to that using less resources than it would need to use for processing an UDP or TCP packet.